# Dotnet build keeps failing in the dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a simple asp net web api application. The folder structure is showing in the screenshot below. However, I keep having issue with the `RUN dotnet build` at line 16 in the Dockerfile.
I know that it's just a matter of incorrect path here, but I could not figure out what goes wrong.
Below is my Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestApi.csproj", "TestApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestApi/TestApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestApi"
RUN dotnet build "TestApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "TestApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```

Here is the error that I'm getting when executing `docker build -t testapi .`

```
#15 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"TestApi.csproj\" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "TestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
1.173   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
2.757 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TestApi/TestApi.csproj]
2.765
2.766 Build FAILED.
2.766
2.766 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TestApi/TestApi.csproj]
2.767     0 Warning(s)
2.767     1 Error(s)
2.767
2.767 Time Elapsed 00:00:02.15
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |     COPY . .
  15 |     WORKDIR "/src/TestApi"
  16 | >>> RUN dotnet build "TestApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
  17 |
  18 |     FROM build AS publish
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"TestApi.csproj\" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Can anyone help me ? Thank you

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I have added my Dockerfile source code.

Comment: Much better, but can you edit to include the error(s) you're getting?

Comment: This error seems pretty self-explanatory, assuming this is your code you're compiling: "error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/TestApi/TestApi.csproj..."

Comment: But in .net 8, we dont have 'Main' method anymore...

Comment: Not according to the compiler you're using.

Comment: @tadman I was able to solve my problem (see my answer). It does not have anything to do with the `Main` method. I guess the error message is not clear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the issue that I have by switching the docker instruction.
I moved the `COPY` below the `WORKDIR` and everything works.

Here is the working Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestApi.csproj", "TestApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestApi/TestApi.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/TestApi" #This line originally was below the COPY
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "TestApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "TestApi.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApi.dll"]
```